# kendo row template syntax (bound from html table)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, templates, html-table, kendo-grid

i have some syntax issues in my kendo grid template

I have a table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped " id="MapDetails">
    <thead>
    <tr class="">
        <th data-field="firstname">First Name</th>
        <th data-field="surname">Surname</th>
        <th data-field="class">Class</th>
        <th data-field="age">Current Age</th>
        @{

            foreach (MapDetail geMapDetailHead in Model.mapDetails)
            { 
               ....
               <th></th>
             }
        }
       </thead>
      <tbody>
       </tbody>
</table>
<script id="gridtemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<tr>
    <td>
        #= firstname #
    </td>
    <td>
        #= surname #
    </td>
    <td>
        #= birthdate #
    </td>
    <td>
        #= classname #
    </td>

</tr>
```

Now i bind the table to kendo grid and define a row template like this

```
$("#MapDetails")
        .kendoGrid(
    {
        sortable: true,
        dataSource: {
            data:values,
            pageSize: 2
        },
        pageable: true,
        resizable: false,
        columnMenu: true,
        scrollable:true,
        navigatable: true,
        editable: "incell",

        rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#gridtemplate").html())
    });
```

this works fine but within gridtemplate, i now need to do something as follows

```
    <script id="gridtemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
 <tr>
    <td>
        #= firstname #
    </td>
    <td>
        #= surname #
    </td>
    <td>
        #= birthdate #
    </td>
    <td>
        #= classname #
    </td>
    #=foreach(var r in results)
       {
      //if r.assessmentid == assessment in header (mapdetails)
      <td>r.resultvalue</td>
else
<td></td>
 }

     # 
</tr>
```

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: this works fine but within gridtemplate, i now need to do something as follows...which has some syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the following

```
<tr>
...
#for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++){
        if(results[i].ResultTypeID == -9999){ #
      <td> #= results[i].NotesLong #</td>      
    # }
    else{
    #           
    <td>            
        #= results[i].ResultValue #
    </td>
    # } }#
 <tr>
```

Comment: So your issue is fixed?